# Counting days between two dates access based on field type

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the first and last date of periods of time, I need a count of the number of days '`sickness`' between those two dates. I am having trouble getting the count to work correctly. The count as I've set it up is calculating every day of sickness regardless of the time period below is an example of what I mean.

```
EAN      FirstDate    LastDate  DaysLost
24659   02/03/2016  04/03/2016  5
24659   07/03/2016  08/03/2016  5
14659   23/02/2016  26/02/2016  14
14659   29/02/2016  04/03/2016  14
14659   07/03/2016  11/03/2016  14
```

What i would like to see is:

```
EAN      FirstDate    LastDate  DaysLost
24659   02/03/2016  04/03/2016  3
24659   07/03/2016  08/03/2016  2
14659   23/02/2016  26/02/2016  4
14659   29/02/2016  04/03/2016  5
14659   07/03/2016  11/03/2016  5
```

There are two categories that make up the first date to last date and they are '`rest day`' and '`sickness`'. I am only interested in seeing the days lost due to '`sickness`' between the first and last date.

The first and last date are taken from a `tmp_table` that extracts data from a table with all dates for each person. It then counts the consecutive days that are rest days and sickness to get the one period of absence.

Is there a way i can just see the '`sickness`' between the two dates?

Current Query:

```
SELECT tbl_PaysysData.EAN, tmp_Occurences.FirstDate, tmp_Occurences.LastDate, Count(dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceType) AS DaysLost INTO tmp_OccurencesandDaysLost
FROM (tmp_Occurences INNER JOIN tbl_PaysysData ON tmp_Occurences.EAN = tbl_PaysysData.EAN) INNER JOIN dim_AbsenceTypes ON tbl_PaysysData.AbsenceType = dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceType
WHERE (((dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceType)="sickness"))
GROUP BY tbl_PaysysData.EAN, tmp_Occurences.FirstDate, tmp_Occurences.LastDate;
```

Comment: Show us your current query!

Comment: That would probably help! See above

Comment: you just need the difference between these dates, right ?

Comment: No not exactly, there are two categories that make up the first and last date; 'rest day' and 'sickness'. i want to know how many days between the two dates are 'sickness'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this enough ? DATEDIFF would give you the difference between those dates, which is the actual days of sickness ?

```
SELECT 
    tbl_PaysysData.EAN, 
    tmp_Occurences.FirstDate, 
    tmp_Occurences.LastDate,
    DATEDIFF(day,tmp_Occurences.FirstDate,tmp_Occurences.LastDate) AS DaysLost 
INTO tmp_OccurencesandDaysLost
FROM tmp_Occurences 
INNER JOIN tbl_PaysysData ON tmp_Occurences.EAN = tbl_PaysysData.EAN 
INNER JOIN dim_AbsenceTypes ON tbl_PaysysData.AbsenceType = dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceType
WHERE dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceType="sickness"
GROUP BY tbl_PaysysData.EAN, tmp_Occurences.FirstDate, tmp_Occurences.LastDate;
```

Comment: The days sickness between the two dates is not necessarily the difference though that is the problem. The firstdate and lastdate can have a mix of 'rest days' and 'sickness' between them. I need to know how many days between the firstdate and lastdate are sickness. The query i have put together just gives me a total of all the days lost due to sickness regardless of what is in firstdate and lastdate as in the first table of my original question.

Comment: Hi Noobie,

Just trying to run your query an i get a syntax error for a missing operator, i can't seem to find it. It's probably staring me in the face but im new to SQL and I'm struggling to spot it!

`tmp_Occurences.EAN = tbl_PaysysData.EAN 
INNER JOIN dim_AbsenceTypes ON tbl_PaysysData.AbsenceType = dim_AbsenceTypes.AbsenceTyp`

Somewhere in there

Comment: If there were two dates to count sickness, then it can be added to the `WHERE` condition, like date between two dates.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Noobie, the issues with your code was due to missing parentheses as there are multiple inner joins. I ran the code and it doesn't give me what i need. I need to know how many of the dates between `FromDate` and `ToDate` are sickness. Because a period of absence can contain `sickness` and `rest Day` a `datediff` just gives the number of days in the absences I need the number of days sickness in the absence

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think you need the dates on which sickness was recorded.

Comment: Yes that's what i need, i need to know betwenn `FromDate` and `ToDate` on which days was sickness recorded and i need a total. Any Ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the table, I can't say :( Show your tables, and atleast somebody would be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'01-01-2016','02-02-2016') AS DaysLost
```

If you need more info about the DATEDIFF function read this:
[W3Schools DateDiff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Comment: Thanks rui, can i use my firstdate and lastdate fields in the datediff?

Comment: I think so. You could try something like this:
`SELECT DATEDIFF(day,(Select FirstDate from sickness where EAN=''),(Select LastDate from sickness where EAN='')) AS DaysLost`

Comment: This is Access, so: `SELECT DATEDIFF("d",#01-01-2016#,#02-02-2016#) AS DaysLost`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I was not sure about access syntax.